# How to omit directory from backup

Tags: backup

I am trying to edit a backup script so it will work for me. My issue is that if I set the directory path I wish to backup, then it would also backup the directory containing the backups :)

The script: https://github.com/todiadiyatmo/bash-backup-rotation-script/blob/master/backup_rotation.sh

currently most of my allocated space is in `/home`

```
root@encorepvp:/home/jo# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        20G  2.3G   16G  13% /
devtmpfs         32G  4.0K   32G   1% /dev
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            6.3G  1.5M  6.3G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             32G  4.0K   32G   1% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/md3        1.8T   29G  1.7T   2% /home
```

I have a dir in `/home` called `backups` so I am looking to omit that directory from the backup using say `-x /home/backups`  How would I go about implementing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a dir in `/home` called `backups` so I am looking to omit that directory from the backup using say `-x /home/backups`. How would I go about implementing this?

To go about implementing this you would look through [the script](https://github.com/todiadiyatmo/bash-backup-rotation-script/blob/master/backup_rotation.sh) and discover the relevant lines for making the directory backup:

```
# Compress tables and files
cd $TARGET_DIR
tar -czf $BACKUP_DIR/backup.incoming/$backup_filename -C $BACKUP_DIR/backup.incoming/ mysql_dump.sql $TARGET_DIR
```

You would discover that it uses `tar`, so you would look up the [man page for tar](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tar) and determine that the *exclude* option is `--exclude` rather than `x`. You would then apply the changes to the file and test it.

Rather than excluding a fixed directory it would make sense - in the context of the script - to use the variable that declares the backups directory, `$BACKUP_DIR`.

```
tar -czf $BACKUP_DIR/backup.incoming/$backup_filename -C $BACKUP_DIR/backup.incoming/ --exclude $BACKUP_DIR mysql_dump.sql $TARGET_DIR
```

While you were editing the script, it would be even better if you were to (trivially) modify large parts of the script so that it could cope with directory names containing whitespace and other strangenesses. You would do this by quoting most of the variables. For example, the `tar` section would become this:

```
# Compress tables and files
cd "$TARGET_DIR"
tar -czf "$BACKUP_DIR/backup.incoming/$backup_filename" -C "$BACKUP_DIR/backup.incoming/" --exclude "$BACKUP_DIR" mysql_dump.sql "$TARGET_DIR"
```

Comment: Hey, cheers for your help! So far it seems to work as intended. I was just wondering if you would be able to confirm for me that I need to add ` --ignore-failed-read` to fix the error: file changed as we read it

Comment: @JoeM if you add `--ignore-failed-read` you risk making your backups useless. Actually, worse than useless because you would think they were fine until you needed to use them.

Comment: So what would you suggest?

Comment: @JoeM off the top of my head, `lvm` snapshots, or perhaps repeating the `tar` "until it works". You'd probably be better off asking a new question (possibly linking to this one for context) because you'll get more people considering the issue, and therefore potentially better quality answers.